# Extjs form is dirty after setting default values

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with isDirty() method of form component in extjs 4.1. After setting default values of fields in a form by

> Ext.getCmp(id).setValue(value)

`form.isDirty()` returns false as if it's been modified.I don't know how to clean the form after setting it's default values and just call `isDirty()` to alert user that form has got dirtied after setting it's default values.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: isDirty() == false indicates no changes.  When isDirty() == true indicates unsaved changes. Or am I getting nuts??

Comment: I think he meant to say it returns true

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [`trackResetOnLoad`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-trackResetOnLoad)?